# Shell how to execute a function in an if statement

Tags: bash, shell

I have two functions.

The function return `0-255`, I want to captures the `return number` in an if statement.

I want to compare their values without `declare var` and `$?`

What should I do?

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

add(){
    echo "add $1 $2 $3"
    return $(($1+$2+$3))
}

sub(){
    echo "sub $1 $2 $3"
    return $(($1-$2-$3))
}

add 1 2 3
if [[ $? != "6" ]]; then
    echo "succ"
else
    echo "fail"
fi

# The code I expect is like this
if [[ $(add 1 2 3) != $(sub 10 2 2) ]]; then
    echo "succ"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

The code prints

```
add 1 2 3
fail
succ
```

I know the sub function will overflow, But that's not important.

**answer: only use `$?` to captures `return`**

Comment: What is the expected range of returned values for `fun1` and `fun2`? Only `0/1`, or any valid exit code?

Comment: @randomir The function not only return number, maybe return filename or other string. I want to compare they.

Comment: Bash functions can `return` only an 8-bit unsigned integer (0-255) - the command exit status. The values `128+n` are reserved for situations when command is terminated by signal `n`, so, you better keep the return value in range `0-127`. To "return" anything else (text), you should use function's stdout, not exit status.

Comment: I think the main confusion, as also indicated in comments to chepner's answer, is the difference between exit status and return value. Here is a good overview: [BashFAQ/084](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/084)

Comment: @randomir thank, I modify my question,

Comment: StackOverflow's help center states explicitly that our purpose is "practical, answerable" questions. Defining your question in such a way as to only accept an answer contrary to best practices (which makes your code needlessly fragile and frustrates error reporting) is intentionally and gratuitously *impractical*, which puts it outside this definition.

Comment: If your goal is to avoid the performance overhead of command substitution, there are good ways to do that; abusing `$?` is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` captures output, not the return value. The most directly implementation would be to put a command list in the condition:

```
if fun1 1 2 3; r1=$?; fun2; r2=$?; [[ $r1 != $r2 ]]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

However, it's a little odd to be *comparing* status codes. Typically, if by success you mean both functions have a 0 exit status, you would just run both functions in an `&&` list (assuming you don't need to run `fun2` if `fun1` fails first.

```
if fun1 1 2 3 && fun2; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: Your first code is `declare var`, which is not easy to read in the if statement.And My function not only return number, maybe it will return filename or other string, I want to compare they.

Comment: Your `fun2` doesn't produce any output; don't confuse the return value with output; they are not the same thing.

Comment: Which is to say, your attempt *does* what you ask: it compares the output of the two functions. The problem seems to be with the implementation of `fun1` and/or `fun2`.

Comment: So how do I captures `return number` in an if statement. I know `$(...)` captures output。 But I need to `echo` some tip to the user, I just want to use `return number`. I have modified the question.please relook.

Comment: As I've shown; you have to use `$?` after the function returns. Note that you are abusing the shell function; a return status isn't meant to return data. "Functions" aren't really functions; they are really just simple scripts. Only use `return` to return 0 for success or a non-zero value between 1 and 255 to indicate some sort of error. (In most cases, there is no need to be specific about the error; just return 1.)

Comment: So, just only use `$?` to captures `return`? Thank you help me!

Comment: @Ahaochan The return status of a function is really just supposed to indicate whether it worked (status = 0) or failed (nonzero status, where the specific value may indicate specifically what went wrong). Please don't try to use it for something else, you're just going to run into more confusion. If you want to return a number that means something other than success/failure, have the function *output* it, and then capture it with `$( )`.